# Rematry oshkabus

Tags: wordplay, rebus

*I just got another picture in the mail, and can't for the life of me piece together why I've been getting such unusual letters...*

[image]

---

<sup><sup>To make things easier for colourblind solvers: the second panel is #FF7F50, the fourth panel is #008080 and the bottom numbers/arrow are #FF0000.</sup></sup>

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but the title is the word "matryoshka" nested inside "rebus".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Each of the rebus works as follows:

> A string ***X*** is derived from the rebus itself, and a string **Y** from the overall typesetting (font size, color etc) of the rebus. The answer is then ***X*** placed inside **Y**, since the image literally shows ***X*** in (the style) **Y**. The cute figures below each of the top four images act as definitions for the answer, allowing us to confirm our answers as we progress.

Rebus #1:

> The rebus is ***L IN DF*** written in **BOLD**, so the answer is **B*LINDF*OLD**.

Rebus #2:

> ***P OR E*** in **CORAL** giving **COR*PORE*AL**.

Rebus #3:

> ***T IF IC*** in **ARIAL** giving **AR*TIFIC*IAL**.

Rebus #4:

> ***E TO T*** in **TEAL**, giving **TE*ETOT*AL**.

And there's more!

> As hinted by the numbers below, we can take the 3rd, 7th, 7th and 4th letters of these answers to form a new rebus:
>  [image: Metarebus]

So the final answer is:

> ***CT IF IE*** in **RED**, giving **RE*CTIFIE*D**.

Comment: Wow! Very nice!

Comment: Well done, it's all spot on :)